# How to correct the indentation of line numbers of algorithm2e package when used with beamer class?

Tags: beamer, indentation, algorithm2e, line

When using the algorithm2e package with the beamer class I get a different indentation for the line numberings than when using it with other classes.

With beamer class they look like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \frame{
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{My algorithm}
            \While{something holds}{
                calculate something
            }
            output something
        \end{algorithm}
    }
\end{document}
```

But I would like to have them like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{My algorithm}
            \While{something holds}{
                calculate something
            }
            output something
        \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Because the problem is so simple I was surprised that after nearly half an hour searching I could not find this question already asked somewhere else. I apologize if this is the case.

Comment: I think this will solve the problem:\IncMargin{1em}
        \begin{algorithm}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Def in **algorithm2e**:

`\IncMargin{length}` increases the size of the `\algomargin` by the length given in argument.

`\DecMargin{length}` decreases the size of the `\algomargin` by the length given in argument.

`\SetAlCapHSkip{length}` sets the horizontal skip before Algorithm: in caption when used in
ruled algorithm.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \frame{
    text test!
    \IncMargin{1.5em}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \SetAlCapHSkip{.7em}
            \caption{My algorithm}
            \While{something holds}{
                calculate something
            }
            output something
        \end{algorithm}
        \DecMargin{1.5em}
    text test!
    }
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Although it looks a little bit like a hack to me (why 1.5em and .7em?) it solves my problem. Thank you very much.